# Switched from SuPHP to FCGI - CURL error 23: Failed writing body

Tags: php, curl, fastcgi, suphp

We just updated our server (WHM) to use FCGI instead of SuPHP, and now we're getting errors from CURL:

```
[curl] 23: Failed writing body (0 != 8)
```

I'm guessing this is related to ownership / permissions, but I'm not sure.

Where does CURL write body's to by default, or how would I be able to tell where this one is trying to write to, and what would need to be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: Needs more info: When do you get this error? Do you have code that triggers it?

Answer (score 0):

i added `sudo` and it worked for me,try to check the owner permissions on the folder you want to download those content 
since curl writes in the current directory if you dont specify the desired folder as first argument like
 `sudo curl /home/eliethesaiyan/curldownloads http://desiredcontent`